# Highcharts: Show x axis for missing data but ignoring certain area

Tags: highcharts

I want to use the Highcharts StockChart library to make a chart. Here's more info on the chart I need to create:

- The type of the chart is `datetime`
- The data is being updated on every minute (it's data from stocks), so the chart is being constantly updated.
- The data of the chart is from 9:00am to 11:40am and then from 12:35pm to 3:00pm (there's a lunch break).
- The data is being shown with bars in an interval of 5 minutes (data is received for every 5 minutes except for the lunch break).
- The bars will start to be drawn from left to right as the data is received.
- The bars width needs to be the same size regardless of how many data is being shown on the chart.
- The labels of x axis of the chart need to be always the same and on the same position (from 9:00am to 3:00pm every hour) even when there's missing data (a line must be drawn on the x axis).

So, I'm using the `max` property set to that day at 3:00pm on the x axis of the chart. With this, I can:

- Have the bars width to be the same
- Have the x axis be drawn regardless of the missing data on the same interval (until 3pm).

Everything works ok until the lunch break (11:40am). However, when receiving data for 12:35pm (after lunch break), the chart will ignore the `max` property and the last line of the x axis that is drawn is until 1pm (this line needs to be drawn until 3pm). I assume that this is because until 11:40am all the data for 5 minutes is present, so the chart understands the interval on which the data needs to be drawn and also can draw the x axis lines on the same interval. But as soon as there's a gap on the data, the chart doesn't know anymore if data will keep coming in an interval of 5 minutes, so will just take into consideration all the data that has received until now, ignoring the `max` property.

I have tried different options in order to solve the issue:

- I used `ordinal` property set to false. With this, I can solve the issue of the missing x axis labels until 3pm, but the issue is that the lunch break will have a gap on the chart. I need to merge the lunch break and having the x axis labels drawn until 3pm.
- I tried to use the `tickInterval` property and was able to set the interval of the x axis but only for the data that is being drawn. However, the x axis label it still until 1pm and needs to be until 3pm.
- I tried to use the `breaks` property for the lunch break while using the `ordinal` property set to false but didn't work. Also, the chart needs to be merged on the lunch break; using this property will create a gap on purpose, so this property won't help me to fix this issue.

So, I noticed that the interval is being changed correctly where there's data, but the lines are not being drawn where there's no data on the x axis (only until 1pm and not until 3pm). And if I use the `ordinal` property, it will show all the x axis lines for the missing data, but need to hide the gap for the lunch break.

Any help with this is appreciated =)

UPDATE:

I noticed that when there's still no data, if using v1.3.1 of highcharts (the one I'm currently using), the x axis lines are being drawn correctly until 3pm, but if using the latest version this doesn't happen. It seems that the `max` property is being ignored for the latest version.

Including the links of jsfiddle for my code on the comments (since stackoverflow doesn't allow me to post many links because don't have enough reputation).

Comment: Chart until 11:40am: Using v1.3.1: jsfiddle.net/K4Cj6/195, Using latest version (v5.0.14): jsfiddle.net/K4Cj6/196. Chart until 12:40pm: Using v1.3.1: jsfiddle.net/K4Cj6/197, Using latest version (v5.0.14): jsfiddle.net/K4Cj6/198. Chart with all the bars (works well with both versions):
 Using v1.3.1: https://jsfiddle.net/K4Cj6/199/
, Using latest version (v5.0.14): https://jsfiddle.net/K4Cj6/200/.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve what I wanted. In the end what I did was to create null data to fill this gap for the lunch break. Also, I created null data for the remaining data until 3pm, that way the x axis lines were drawn properly: https://jsfiddle.net/K4Cj6/201/:
    `[1504528800000,null,null,null,null]`

Thanks anyway guys =)